# DAX function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem that is looking for dates in the same month in a column and if the dates have the same id, I want to take the difference of the dates. Can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can there only be 2 dates?
If so (or if you are ok with max and min dates) you could write a measure like:

```
Date_difference = 
var sid=Table[Id]
return
Calculate(DATEDIFF(MIN(Table[Date]), MAX(Table[Date]), DAY),Filter(Table,Table[Id]=sid))
```

What this measure does is first "saves" the Id you are looking for, then calculates day difference for max and min date when id is the "saved" Id.
If you want to not use varibales, you can use Earlier function:

```
Date_difference = Calculate(DATEDIFF(MIN(Table[Date]), MAX(Table[Date]), DAY),Filter(Table,Table[Id]=earlier(Table[Id])))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have 2 columns, the Date column and the Id column. I have multiple dates and also multiple ids. What I am looking is to check for a duplicate id and for each duplicate id, calculate the date difference in days.